# Add modification time to the filename

Tags: files, rename, date

I need to add the creation date of the file with the file name. Eg if a creation date of the file Test is 22 Mar 2017, then I need to change it as test_rbc_22032017. I am able to perform for a single file but not sure how to create a script to change the name for n number of files in a given directory. I tried the below but no luck

```
for f in /path ; do mv -n ""$f"_RBS_(date -r "$f" +"%Y%M%D")"; done
```

but no luck. please suggest a solution

Comment: Given unix by default has no creation date, how are you obtaining the creation date of the file?

Comment: Command substitution is `$(somecmd...)`, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=command+substitution) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: it's modified date as files that I am looking for is created on everyday basis so both are same . We can take it as modified date and unchanged

Comment: What happened when you tried that command? Please include that information in the question.

Comment: i made few changes and used the below       'for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "$f-RBS_$(date +%Y%m%d -r "${f}")"; done' it's working fine

Comment: @user2310119:  What do you think you are trying do to with `""$f"_…`?  The first two quotes cancel out, leaving `$f"_…`.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that the `mv` command takes a source and destination, you are only providing one.

Next thing is the date format, according to your information you want %Y for the year, %m for the month and %d for the day, see `man date` for an explanation of the differences between the sequences.

Third point is that you only provide the path (`for f in /path`) instead of referring to files (`for f in /path/*`). So a working example will be:

```
for f in /path/*; do mv -n "$f" "${f}_$(date -r "$f" +'%Y%m%d')"; done
```

Comment: @Lambert:  Please quote `$f`, as in `date -r "$f" +…`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command has a few problems:

```
for f in /path ; do mv -n ""$f"_RBS_(date -r "$f" +"%Y%M%D")"; done
```

- `for f in /path` will only go once around the loop (with `f` = `/path`).  You probably want `for f in /path/*` to consider every file in the `/path/` directory (if you want to consider files in subdirectories, that's a whole nother question).
- `mv` needs two arguments.  The source is obviously `"$f"`.  The destination needs to be the transformed name.
- You missed the `$` in the `$(...)` command substitution.
- The format string for `date` doesn't match your description (and you probably want month and day rather than minute and short-date)
- You're using date of modification, not creation date (which isn't kept, on most filesystem types).  I'll leave this as-is.
- Your description implies that you want the filename to be in lower case.

With the above corrected (apart from the choice of which date to use), we end up with

```
for f in /path/* ; do mv -n "$f" "${f,,}_rbc_$(date -r "$f" +'%d%m%Y')"; done
```

Another thing to consider is that if you're doing this more than once in the same place, you might want to move the files to a different directory or test to see if they already have a plausible suffix (either remove it before adding the new one, or just leave such files untouched).

Answer (score 0):

try this kind operation, and adapt it to your situation:
`now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
file="/nas/backup_$now.sql"`

so should work: `for f in /path ; do mv -n "$f" "${f}_RBS_$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")"; done`

Comment: Another query reg the same. I want to find a file in a unix directory and if exist I want to assign the filename along with its modified time stamp to a variable like the below

variable=(find the file name, if exist add the filename with _a string _and modified time stamp) is it possible.

Answer (score -3):

This is the best way to do it.

Here is the script to add the creation date of the file for n number of files in given directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/home/modassir/data/"
listoffiles=$(ls -1 /home/modassir/data)


for f in $listoffiles; do
   file=$(date -r $path$f +'%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S')
   mv $path''$f'' $path''$f''_rbc_''$file''
done;
```

`/home/modassir/data` is the directory name

Comment: No, using ls is definitely not the best way, see [Bash pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  Also, the back-to-back single-quotes are useless, they just contain an empty string that gets concatenated to the variables (after [word-splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target))

Comment: go to https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial and search for "Bash for loop" .If I am wrong,then what is this.                                                                                                                                                To list all files,we can use ls . different website says different format.

Comment: Sure, as long as any of the filenames don't contain whitespace, glob characters or unprintable characters (in the opinion of your local `ls`) and don't start with dashes, it just might work. But you could also use a glob in the the `for` loop to begin with.

Comment: @Modassir - there's a lot of bad advice in that "tutorial".  You should try to forget you ever read it, and go somewhere more reliable, such as [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: @Toby ok.buddy I will start reading Greg's Wiki.If I will find it;s better tutorials then will go ahead with this.Otherwise,will follow tutorials point.